# Emacs started adding extra tabs in when I paste into it on OS X

Tags: emacs

This always worked fine before, but all of a sudden when I paste into emacs from somewhere else on OS X (using cmd-c cmd-v), I get a bunch of extra spaces/tabs. Example, say I have the following YML:

```
- name: something
  hosts: some_host
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:

    - name: do something
      some_module:
        group: something
```

When I copy that and then paste it into emacs, it's suddenly formatted:

```
- name: something
    hosts: some_host
      gather_facts: False

        tasks:

              - name: do something
                      some_module:
                                  group: something
```

It looks like it's double the number of spaces on every line. I've tried this in both yaml-mode and fundamental mode. Everything used to work fine. What gives?

Comment: Does this still happen if you launch Emacs with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @Chris It still comes out with unexpected spaces on some lines, but they're different.

Comment: I wonder if you are pasting tabs that are just displaying with different widths. Try turning on `whitespace-mode` to see if that gives any insight.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, this is very weird. It looks like this happened because I updated emacs to 24.4 (I was updating a lot of stuff through homebrew and didn't notice). Turns out this is possibly somehow a "feature," though how is beyond me. You can disable it by adding `(electric-indent-mode 0)` to your .emacs. More info [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1161786).

Comment: Not only does this happen when copy/pasting stuff, but when getting Emacs to autocomplete code for you, see my [post](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10896/avoid-extra-tabs-when-generating-haskell-code-with-ghc-mod) on Emacs Exchange. Thankfully, your solution works just as well for me :). Btw, you should mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: Thank you! This has been driving me crazy for a *long* while, only got around to searching for a solution today. Such a simple fix for such a frustrating issue :)

Comment: Should've called it `evil-indent-mode`. This worked for me. Thank you for your answer.